# Pass an array to a function in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, function, user-defined-functions

is it somehow possible to pass an an array to a function like this example function:

```
send_mail($adress, $data)
{
    return $data[0];
}
```

?

So could the input variable be an array? If yes, could someone show me an example, please?

Comment: Return an array by a function or pass an array to a function?

Comment: yes. example: above; your code.

Comment: @itachi It doesn't seem to work this way. To: user4035 Pass an array to a function.

Comment: `It doesn't seem to work.` what is the error? __PS. Your title, question and comment contradicts each other__. in title, you want to return an array, in comment, you want to pass an array to a function. what is your __Exact__ need?

Comment: @itachi Pass an array to function as he said in comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it somehow possible to pass an an array to a function like in the example?

Yes, passing a function to your `send_mail` is perfectly fine. But the `[0]` access you are making inside the function is a little bit dangerous:

```
send_mail($adress, $data)
{
    return $data[0];
}
```

what if `$data` is an empty array? You should check if the first element is present ( with `(count($data) > 0)` or any other equivalent) and only then, use it.

There's also a little thing in PHP called [*type hinting*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) that will force the user of `send_mail` to use an array variable, otherwise a PHP error will be triggered:

```
send_mail($adress, array $data) { ... }
```

You should be using that when you can in order to have more robust code.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're asking about but you can access all arguments by using this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php

that way you can pass any number of arguments to your function and grab them from func_get_arg.

Is this what you're asking about?

Answer (score 1):

To pass an Array to a Function

```
function addall($array_var){
<do something using the array $array_var>
}
 $array_var=array(1,2,3,4);

addall($array_var);
```

To return an Array from a Function

```
    function addall($i,$j,$k,$l){
$array_var=array($i,$j,$k,$l);
return $array_var
}

$array_var=array(1,2,3,4);

addall(1,2,3,4);
```

P.S: The function can have any no of arguments, each of the arguments can be a single var or an array.

Comment: you are calling a function before defining it.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an array to a function, and return an array from a function. By default, arrays are passed **by value** (a scalar), meaning that it is a copy of the array, and changes within the function do not affect the original array.

In the code that follows the first function call doesn't affect the content of the tempArray. In the second function call, that is passed **by reference** using the ampersand (&), the original array is changed.

```
$tempArray = array();
$tempArray[] = "hello";

function testFn($theArray) {
    $theArray[] = "there";
    return $theArray;
}

$result = testFn($tempArray);
echo print_r($result);    // hello, there
echo print_r($tempArray);    // hello

function testFnRef(&$theArray) {
    $theArray[] = "there";
    return $theArray;
}

$result = testFnRef($tempArray);
echo print_r($result);    // hello, there
echo print_r($tempArray);    // hello, there
```

[function arguments](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php)